# Parsing JSON array created from PHP array

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "ocena_ocena": "2",
        "ocena_profesor": "\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u043e \u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0438\u045b",
        "ocena_napomena": "",
        "ocena_datum": "31.12.2015."
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "ocena_ocena": "5",
        "ocena_profesor": "\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u043e \u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0438\u045b",
        "ocena_napomena": "",
        "ocena_datum": "22.12.2015."
    }
}
```

I am using ajax to get this JSON. I tried parsing it like this:

```
request.done(function(response) {
    alert(response.ocena_ocena);
});
```

Could someone please help me with this?

I also need to know how can I do a `foreach` statement with json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JSON represents a JavaScript object, you should include the `attribute` name (if we consider JavaScript object to be a map, then, we need to use the `key`).

Try

```
response["1"].ocena_ocena
```

or

```
response["3"].ocena_ocena
```

Since you are returning a JSON object from server instead of an array, to iterate over its properties, you could do

```
for (var i in response) {
    console.log(response[i].ocena_ocena);
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(response).forEach(function f(e) {console.log(response[e].ocena_ocena)})
```

If you could modify your server side code to return JSON that looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "ocena_ocena": "2",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "ocena_ocena": "5",
        ...
    }
]
```

then you could iterate over it more easily

```
response.forEach(function f(e) {console.log(e.ocena_ocena)})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do a foreach statement with this code?

Comment: Updated the answer, `forEach` will work only on array - in your case you don't have an array - unless you modify server side code and send array as response

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!